# select directory for image source

Tags: image, select, directory

I am developing a slideshow to work in conjunction with my CMS currently users can upload direct to the images directory however you then need to enter the details into the  handler for each image 1 by 1 example

```
           <div class="content"><div id="galleria">
        <a href="images/1.jpg">
            <img data-title="Picture 1"
                 data-description="Picture 1."
                 src="images/1.jpg">
        </a>
        <a href="images/2.jpg">
            <img data-title="Picture 2"
                 data-description="Picture 2"
                 src="images/2.jpg">
        </a>
        <a href="images/3.jpg">
            <img data-title="Picture 3"
                 data-description="Picture 3"
                 src="images/3.jpg">
        </a>
        <a href="images/4.jpg">
            <img data-title="Picture 4"
                 src="images/4.jpg">
        </a>
        <a href="images/5.jpg">
            <img data-title="Picture 5"
                 src="images/5.jpg">
        </a>
        <a href="images/6.jpg">
            <img data-title="Picture 6"
                 data-description="picture 6"
                 src="images/6.jpg">
        </a>
        <a href="images/7.jpg">
            <img data-title="Picture 7"
                 src="images/7.jpg">
        </a>
        <a href="images/8.jpg">
            <img data-title="picture 8"
                 src="images/8.jpg">
        </a>
        <a href="images/9.jpg">
            <img data-title="Picture 9"
                 src="images/9.jpg">
        </a>
        <a href="images/10.jpg">
        <img data-title="Picture 10"
            src="images/10.jpg">
        </a>
    </p>
</div>

<script>
```

is there a way i can just specify a folder and it would add all photos inside the folder? so when i add a new photo the script would then automatically add the image to the slideshow as long as its in the specified folder

Comment: I would need this to work on the website i have seen it done before but cant think how

Answer (score -1):

I personally see a lot of parsing errors, but to answer your question: There is a way. Yes, you can specify a folder. However, this will have to be a website that is not hosted, and is only an HTML file somewhere that can be opened. You just have to get the directory name (ie, C:\Users\ThisUser\Desktop\HTMLDirectory). Insert that as the image source and you should be good. This should work. :)

Edit 1: MAKE SURE that you keep the folder name and location the same at all times, or else this fails.